# Objective-C add up class method not working as expected

Tags: objective-c

So I was writing my first class in Objective-C and I found a weird issue that I can't seem to fix. I created a class, called Vector, and implemented a method called addUpWith. Everything worked fine, but the output screen always shows the following:

```
(6, -4)
```

while it should output

```
(8, 7)
```

Below are the three files I used:

**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Vector_Class.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        Vector *vector1 = [Vector initWithX:5 y:9];
        //NSLog(vector1.string);
        Vector *vector2 = [Vector initWithX:3 y:-2];
        //NSLog([vector2 string]);

        Vector *sum = [vector1 addUpWith:vector2];
        NSLog(@"(%i, %i)", [sum x], [sum y]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Vector_Class.h**

```
#ifndef Vector_Class_h
#define Vector_Class_h

@interface Vector : NSObject

//Variables
@property int x;
@property int y;

//Initalizer
+ (Vector*) initWithX: (int) x y: (int) y;

//Getters
- (int) x;
- (int) y;

//Setters
- (void) setX: (int) newValue;
- (void) setY: (int) newValue;

//Functions
- (Vector*) addUpWith: (Vector*) other;
- (NSString*) string;

@end

#endif /* Vector_Class_h */
```

**Vector_Class.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Vector_Class.h"

@implementation Vector : NSObject 

//Variables
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

//Initializer
+ (Vector*) initWithX:(int) x y:(int) y {
    Vector *vector = [Vector new];
    [vector setX: x];
    [vector setY: y];
    return vector;
}

//Getters
- (int) x {
    return x;
}
- (int) y {
    return y;
}

//Setters
-(void) setX: (int) newValue {
    x = newValue;
}

-(void) setY: (int) newValue {
    y = newValue;
}

- (Vector*) addUpWith: (Vector*) other {
    int newX = x + [other x];
    int newY = y + [other y];

    Vector *vector = [Vector initWithX:newX y:newY];
    return vector;
}

- (NSString*) string {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i, %i)", x, y];
}

@end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm always open to healthy criticism, so I'd appreciate it if you point out any other mistakes I made.

Comment: I can't really do much with breakpoints because it only shows the value of the object, not the functions x and y, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here in the implementation of `Vector`:

```
@implementation Vector : NSObject 

//Variables
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
```

It might make it easier to see if I rewrite the code to an equivalent form:

```
static int x = 0;
static int y = 0;

@implementation Vector

// other code

@end
```

By declaring those 2 static ("class" or "shared") variables with the same/similar name as your instance variables would have, your setters and getters end up setting those variables rather than the instance variables you hoped they would. In other words,

```
Vector *vector1 = [Vector initWithX:5 y:9]; // sets x to 5, y to 9

Vector *vector2 = [Vector initWithX:3 y:-2]; // sets x to 3, y to -2
```

So when you call the `addUpWith:` method, you end up with `3 + 3`, and `-2 + -2`, which is `(6, -4)`.

I'm guessing you added the

```
//Variables
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
```

lines to avoid a compile error, since the compiler probably said there were no `x` and `y` variables to set. That's because, by default, when you declare a property with `@property`, the synthesized instance variable is named `_varName`: for example, `_x` and `_y` in your case.

While there are many other changes you could make, the following is one option. There are basically two different ways to handle instance variables, properties, and/or getters and setters in Objective-C classes. The method I show here is the older and original way things were done, before the advent of `@property` like `@rmaddy` uses in their answer. Why bother even showing this way when using `@property` is preferred for modern development? Well, the code you provided seems to be a mix of the 2 different styles; generally you'd use one or the other. My example will show you one way, so you can contrast it with the `@property` way `@rmaddy` has shown in their answer.

Vector.h:

```
@interface Vector : NSObject {
    // these are instance variables
    int x;
    int y;
}

//Initalizer
+ (Vector*) vectorWithX: (int) anX y: (int) aY;

//Getters
- (int) x;
- (int) y;

//Setters
- (void) setX: (int) newValue;
- (void) setY: (int) newValue;

//Functions
- (Vector*)vectorByAddingVector: (Vector*) other;
- (NSString*) string;

@end
```

Vector.m:

```
@implementation Vector

//Initializer
+ (Vector*) vectorWithX:(int) anX y:(int) aY {
    Vector *vector = [Vector new];
    [vector setX: anX];
    [vector setY: aY];
    return vector;
}

//Getters
- (int) x {
    return x;
}
- (int) y {
    return y;
}

//Setters
-(void) setX: (int) newValue {
    x = newValue;
}

-(void) setY: (int) newValue {
    y = newValue;
}

- (Vector*) vectorByAddingVector: (Vector*) other {
    int newX = x + [other x];
    int newY = y + [other y];

    Vector *vector = [Vector vectorWithX:newX y:newY];
    return vector;
}

- (NSString*) string {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i, %i)", x, y];
}

@end
```

Comment: Actually, this won't work as-is. Since this code explicitly overrides both the setter and the getter, the instance variables for the properties will not be automatically synthesized. In other words, there won't be a `_x` or `_y` ivar from the properties. Those variables will need to be explicitly declared. Better yet, get rid of the needless explicit getter and setter methods.

Comment: Regarding your updated answer - it's poor practice to declare ivars in the .h file. Put them in the .m file where they belong. Nothing private should be in the .h file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You have some conflicts with your `x` and `y` values in your `Vector` class. You declare the `x` and `y` properties but then you also needlessly declare the `x` and `y` methods as well as the `setX:` and `setY:` methods. And then in your .m file you needlessly declare global `x` and `y` variables (instead of creating instance variables).

Of all of that, all you need is the `@property` lines in your .h.

Unrelated, instead of declaring the `string` method, simply override the standard `description` method provided through `NSObject`.

Given all of this, your code should be more like:

Vector.h:

```
@interface Vector : NSObject

//Variables
@property int x;
@property int y;

//Initializer
+ (Vector *)initWithX:(int)x y:(int)y;

//Functions
- (Vector *)addUpWith:(Vector *)other;

@end
```

Vector.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Vector_Class.h"

@implementation Vector : NSObject 

//Initializer
+ (Vector *)initWithX:(int)x y:(int)y {
    Vector *vector = [Vector new];
    vector.x = x;
    vector.y = y;

    return vector;
}

- (Vector *)addUpWith:(Vector *)other {
    int newX = self.x + other.x;
    int newY = self.y + other.y;

    Vector *vector = [Vector initWithX:newX y:newY];

    return vector;
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i, %i)", self.x, self.y];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I can't rate two answers as the right one, even though I used them both...